# Point a url in magento app to a different app

Tags: apache, magento

I have a magneto application running on Apache.I want home page of this application to point to a completely different app:

so for example, if

```
localhost:80/
```

was accessed, redirect it to `localhost:3000/` . I want this since we are changing magento app to react app page by page and we have our react app running on localhost:3000, what would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy_pass in Apache **Vhost conf** (Before that, you must enable apache **mod_proxy** module)

Example;

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Do you mind pointing me to a resource for explanation on this? I am new to this PHP apache thing completely

Comment: I added it to:  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf . Is this what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Ofcourse, you find httpd-vhosts.conf file in your web server and than you should add VirtualHost block At the bottom of the page. Finally you should restart Apache. Hope is enough

Comment: Hey, That helped. But instead of  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
, if I add   ProxyPass http://localhost/sbl_next http://localhost:3000/, it doesn't help. The website opens without redirection.If I use your thing as it is, I can't access any of the pages like http://localhost/sbl_next/catalog. How do I do this?

Comment: catalog page should be accessed from localhost/sbl_next only and not from localhost:3000/catalog

Comment: Ok i will try to help. What version of apache are you using?